# Content of cmd in windows

Tags: c++, windows, shell, console

I want to use `std::cin` and `std::cout` in c++ app without using `<iostream>`.
As a understand, when i write something in command prompt shell, it writes in a specific file, from where I can read in my c++ program, using `cin` and `operator>>`,
and when I send some text to shell using `cout` and `operator<<`, that text is written in that same specific file, and then content of file is shown in shell.

So here is my answer, where is that file located, or is it a file or something else.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a file on disk; it's one of the three standard streams created for every process.